# Why am I getting AccessDenied on my S3 static site even though I allowed public access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created static website on Amazon S3. The website loads, but after the first update I get "AccessDenied".

I have disabled "block public access" for the bucket, and I have added my error document and index suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [add a bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html#bucket-policy-static-site)?

By default, Amazon S3 Buckets block public access. This means your *bucket* is not accessible to the internet. Turning this off allows internet traffic to your bucket. However, bucket access does not equal Read/Write access to your *objects*. You must add a policy allowing the public to call `s3:GetObject` for the resources in your bucket. This should do the trick:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-Name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If that didn't work, it's possible you have public access blocked at the account level. You'll need to [open your console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configuring-block-public-access-account.html) and go to "Block Public Access settings for this account."

[image: Amazon S3 console]

From there, click on the 'Edit' button then uncheck the relevant fields.

Comment: Actually, I have tried your suggestions but no luck.

Comment: Do you have any account level restrictions?

Comment: This AWS account created from the control tower, it may be, what access level required, or how to check that?

Comment: @ChandanSharma I added some more info to the answer.

Comment: Hi Corey, already Blocked Public access unchecked

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I get AccessDenied?" Can you provide a screenshot in your answer?

Comment: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>QV4XNMGD4EXF5MFW</RequestId>
<HostId>2fs7h7AX5aGByDE/M0jnU+WeHD4M40IhJVjGDSX7XYZT+4OTrm22YtsvLlsXosqrE8J3NDvVjA4=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: come to this error after refreshing the Home page (The home page load properly but after refresh, we got the error.

Comment: How is the site deployed? Are you going through S3 directly or a CloudFront distribution?

Comment: unfortunately Till now no Chat functions are available for me

Comment: Directly from S3, no CloudFront